# How do I unset a specific vim command?

Tags: vim

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:_
```

I tried to unset the above command this way:

```
unset listchars=tab:>-,trail:_
```

But only get:

```
E492: Not an editor command: unset listchars=tab:>-,trail:_
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 60):

This will reset the listchars option to the default:

```
set listchars&
```

See the [options documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html) for more info.

Comment: will `unset listchars=` work?

Comment: There's no `unset` command.  For toggleable options, you can do `set nooption` (example: `set paste` and `set nopaste`), but listchars is not toggleable.  If you actually want to set listchars to have no value, do: `set listchars=`

Comment: so `set listchars&` is the same as `set listchars=`?

Comment: `set listchars&` sets it to the default setting that it started with, which is `eol:$`

Comment: Handy to know, thanks. Also works for :set rightleft

Answer (score 27):

There are 3 primary ways to unset a variable. I will use the `binary` command here for demonstration purposes. One of them should work.

1. `set nobinary`
2. `set binary&`
3. `set binary!`

Remember to reload the file you are working on for the values to apply again using `:e`